# What is the simplest way to get log files off of an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have logged my NSLog statements to a file in my iPhone app.

What is the simplest way to grab this data off the phone?

Is there a way to copy the file from Xcode's organizer or some other GUI interface/CLI utility like that or do I need to grab the contents of the file programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Xcode Organizer, you can "Download" all of your app's files.

1) Open the Organizer.
2) Connect your device.
3) Select "Applications" under that device.
4) Click the Download button for the application.
5) Save the folder to your Desktop.

Your app's Documents folder will be in the folder that you save, along with the Library and tmp folders for that app.

Answer (score 3):

inside of Xcode (in the organizer) you can click your application, expand it and copy the logs to your local machine

Comment: This only is displaying crash logs.                                     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
               NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory
       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console.log"];
 freopen([logPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);          That is the code that I am using to redirect the NSLogs to a file, that file "console.log" is the file I am trying to grab.

Comment: So the question isn't about NSLog, it's about redirect of stderr - clarify that in your question (title and body) to get better answers - maybe even create a new question.....

Comment: The redirecting of output is irrelevant, and I did make myself clear in the first line of the post "I have logged my NSLog statements to a file in my iPhone app." The question is I have a file that I created in my bundle at runtime, and for ease of use I am wondering if anyone knows a way to grab that file quickly off the device.

Comment: My method (the same as that of Mike Hay below) didn't work?  Then the file isn't being written.

Comment: @Nima - silly question, other than the handholding - how is my answer different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

As the file is in your apps docs folder you can switch on iTunes filesharing in your plist

`UIFileSharingEnabled`

and copy it off the device via the iTunes interface.